# Removing the anonymous instance warning in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instance-variables

I have an anonymous instance created from a class, which in it's custom instance method add it so the superviews layer and animates it, although this works great Xcode gives me a warning, 'Expression result unused', is there any way to remove this error without changing the class?

If I create an instance with a pointer, I just get 'Unused variable 'myIVar'' because I never need to point to it in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never ever seen this warning of which you speak, but you can eliminate the unused variable message with the `__unused` attribute on the declaration.

Comment: Or just comment out the *name* of the variable in the implementation, leaving its type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Hot Licks,

"I've never ever seen this warning of which you speak, but you can eliminate the unused variable message with the `__unused` attribute on the declaration."